# How to load static JavaScript file and css in Django with Pycharm

Tags: python, django

I am new to django , I am unable to set path to load js and css file from directory. When I run server my page is showing without css and js.
I setting file of project I have set static path as:

```
STATIC_URL = '/templates/'
```

and in template directory I have 3 dir named html, js, css.
I am able to load html file from html dir but not js and css.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

Answer (score -1):

Create folder, name it static copy *CSS*,*JS* to that NOT HTML it should remain in the templates directory and Change the `STATIC_URL = '/templates/'` to `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. This is how Django manages the static files(*CSS*,*JS*,*IMAGES*).
Check this out for more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: you don't have to use "/static/" as the STATIC_URL nor to name your static files dir "static", so the only correct part of your answer is the link to the doc - which as already been posted in a comment and is not a proper answer.

Comment: Can we serve the static files and the HTML templates from the same directory that will be named as templates?